# What is the most optimized way of getting a single element from a device array in cuda

Tags: cuda

I have an array on device of huge length and for some condition check I want to access (On Host/ CPU) only one element from middle (say Nth element). What could be the optimized way for doing this.

Do I need to write a kernel that writes Nth location in single element array from the src array and then I copy single element array to host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy single element of an array using `cudaMemcpy`.
Let's say you want to copy `N`-th element of array:

`int * dSourceArray`

to variable

`int hTargetVariable`

You can apply device pointer arithmetics on the host. All you need to do is to move `dSourceArray` pointer by `N` elements ant copy single element:

```
cudaMemcpy(&hTargetVariable, dSourceArray+N, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost)
```

Keep in mind that if you use multiple streams you would like to synchronize the device before transferring the data.

Comment: Wouldn't this imply that N is already known to the host? What happens if it is not?

Comment: If the N is somehow computed on the device, having some global __device__ variable would do it. First you would use cudaMemcpyFromSymbol() to copy the value of N from global __device__ variable and then copy the N-the element as described above.

Answer (score 0):

One addendum to answer 1, you *may* need to take account of the bytes per element of your array. e.g. For an array of arrays of various types on the device:

```
#ifdef CUDA_KERNEL
    char*   mgpu[ MAX_BUF ];    // Device array of pointers to arrays of various types.
#else           
    CUdeviceptr     mgpu[ MAX_BUF ];    // on host, gpu is a device pointer.
    CUdeviceptr     gpu (int n )    { return mgpu[n]; }

CUdeviceptr GPUpointer = m_Fluid.gpu(FGRIDOFF); // Device pointer to FGRIDOFF (int) array
cuMemcpyDtoH (&CPUelement, GPUpointer+(offset*sizeof(int)) , sizeof(int) );
```